# G+ Sign-In Ian Barber Implementation : onConnectionFailed not getting called when disconnecting rebuilding GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, google-plus, google-plus-signin

I have integrated google+ sign in using the developer site and for server side i followed @ianbarber 's solution on riskcompletefailure blog

This how i am bulding the GoogleApiClient:

```
return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
            .addScope(new Scope("email")).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .build();
```

This is how getting the id token in async task

```
scopes = "audience:server:client_id:" + Util.CLIENT_ID_SERVER;
            id = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getActivity(),
                    Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient),
                    scopes);
```

after which createSession is called and based on the response from server it updates the hashMap & rebuild GoogleApiClient and again retries to connect, but it is going to onConnceted() rather than onConnectionFailed() as server returned 401 (no refresh token available)

```
if (cookie.equals("NO_REFRESH")) {
        Log.v(TAG, "create session for " + mAccountName);
        mSessionCookie = null;
        mUserHasRefreshOnServer.put(mAccountName, false);
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "refresh available on server");
        mSessionCookie = cookie;
        mUserHasRefreshOnServer.put(mAccountName, true);
    }
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        Log.v(TAG, "disconnect googleclient ");
    }
    Log.v(TAG, "try connect googleclient ");

    mGoogleApiClient = buildGoogleApiClient();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

this what i need to perform in onConnectionFailed()

```
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {

    if ((mAccountName != null)
            && mUserHasRefreshOnServer.containsKey(mAccountName)
            && mUserHasRefreshOnServer.get(mAccountName) == Boolean.FALSE) {
            getCode(); //code for getting onetime authorization code
    }
```

Please point out what am i doing wrong and for details look at this [document](http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2013/10/google-android-client-server-sign-in.html) i have followed exactly

**EDIT:**

I changed the flow.. replicating exactly this [gist](https://gist.github.com/ianbarber/7105273) but now after sending the id token (provided server doesn't have a refresh & no consent asked) when i go for getCode
i get consent only for Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN and not for offline access hence when i reconnect i still end up in onConnectionFailed with error code=4 (Sign-in required)

But,
The alternate flow wherein if i resolve errors beforehand(consent to Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN) and then go for getCode this time i get this offline access consent also and consequently an onConnected which is what is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a valid state to get into! You can get there if the user has previously signed in, but you have lost the refresh token on the server.

If you look at the gist (which is out of date now since moving to GoogleApiClient of course), you can see we have a getCode call in the onConnected as well: https://gist.github.com/ianbarber/7105273#file-codeactivity-java-L97

```
if (mSessionCookie == null) {
  // If the server hasn't got a refresh token, grab it.
  if(mUserHasRefreshOnServer.containsKey(mAccountName)) {
    getCode();
  } else {
    // Otherwise, just get the session.
    getSession();
  }
}
```

This is precisely for handling that case - we know the user has signed but, but we still need to get a refresh token on the server, so we're going to have to send them down the getCode route and pop a consent dialog via the UserRecoverableAuthException.

Comment: Now after trying the code from the gist. I am getting onConnectionFailed always and the consent dialog for offline access is not coming ..also due to the onstart connect call I am continuously getting the onconnectionfailed and going for get code..though for that I have included a flag to prevent looping..

Comment: I think I have to resolveSignInError before going for get session and get code ..that way I will have to handle all logic in on connected only, about user's state

Comment: Also thanks for your risk complete failure blog ..it would be great if you update that code based on new googleapiclient

Comment: You can certainly resolve sign in error earlier, but you will get double consent dialogs when you retrieve the code. It is certainly a complicated flow, so I understand the difficulties! 

In general, once you've had an on

Comment: You can certainly resolve sign in error earlier, but you will get double consent dialogs when you retrieve the code. It is certainly a complicated flow, so I understand the difficulties! 

In general, if you have a stored account to use for retrieving the id token you can see what the state of the server is, and either go with GoogleAuthUtil or GoogleApiClient depending on the situation. I will certainly make a note to update the blog post and gist though!

Comment: Yes I mean if I resolve errors beforehand than I get a consent for Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN and then when I am going for getCode I will get a consent for offline access..but is there a way where those two consent dialog can be merged into single consent? Looking forward for your updates on the gist..

Comment: There is no way they can be merged - you can just make sure you do the code one first. That's what requires the complicated flow: you have to do: 1 - choose account (without consent) 2: check with server using id token 3: retrieve code if needed 4: connect GoogleApiClient. Basically you should never resolve errors on the GoogleApiClient - the consent dialog should always come from GoogleAuthUtil. Once the user grants there, as long as the scopes match *exactly* in both places, the GoogleApiClient should connect.

Comment: When it just says "offline access" in the consent dialog that's a bit of a red herring. Basically, it will say that whenever you have already granted access to all of the scopes (because it has to say something). If you are calling getToken with the oauth2:server:client_id:api_scope: scope string, then it is requesting offline access, even if the consent dialog doesn't specifically mention it.

Comment: then why i am not getting the onConnected call after providing the consent? and scopes are also matching everywhere.

Comment: You should be, as long as you reconnect the googleapiclient after getting the consent. Could you post your code somewhere?

Comment: Thanks. I updated my gist to GoogleApiClient - https://gist.github.com/ianbarber/7105273 - Looking at yours I see you don't specify the request_visible_actions on the GoogleApiClient version - that could potentially be the oddness. As a side note, this whole thing should get a lot easier in the next version of Google Play Services!

Comment: following the updated gist my problem got solved. Thank you so much ian.